# Custom header buttons on list view removed column names

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink

I'm using the JSLink feature to put some buttons at the top of a list view. A screenshot of the relevant code is posted below. It's working, but a few users have noted that the column names row disappeared. They should be right below the buttons (second screenshot), but don't appear at all. I used the F12 developer tools to inspect elements on the page, but couldn't find that row. I think it's because the JSLink script is overriding the header, and that row is part of the original header.

**Is it possible to have a custom header AND the original column names on a list view?**

Fig. 1 - the custom header code:
[image]

Fig. 2 - the custom header seen on page:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your logic as below

```
(function () {    
    var requestCtx = {};
    requestCtx.Templates = {};
    requestCtx.Templates.Header = overrideHeader;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(requestCtx);

})();

function overrideHeader(ctx) {
    var htmlTmp = RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx);        
    htmlTmp += "<a href='#'>Refresh</a>";

    return htmlTmp;     
}
```

I am using `RenderHeaderTemplate` to get the existing header template.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced 'RenderTableHeader' with 'RenderHeaderTemplate' and my column names are back where they should be.